# Install Certificate on Build Server

Tags: tfs, build, certificate

We have a dream to automate our build process using Visual Studio Online Build 2015 (vNext).

We are developing Desktop application that has Windows Logo program. That's why we have to sign-authenticode every binary and msi-installer file. For that purposes ideally we have to install authenticoding certificate on build server. Please help me with some tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Hosted Build Pool/Controller, you should set up one on-premise build server.

To work with Windows Logo program, the Windows Hardware Certification Kit is required. However, this certificate kit is not installed on the hosted build pool/controller, and you don't have permissions to install it on hosted server either. So, you need to set up one on-premise build server, install the certificate kit on it and register it with VSO. Please check this blog for the steps on how to register a on-premise build server with VSO: http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but we do not understand why we need to install WHCK on that machine, we already have done that certification with Windows App Certification Kit and now we are involved to make robust automated build process on VSO Build 2015 and for it how we understand we should install our certificate on that virtual machine where going build process. For each build VSO Build 2015 creates new virtual machine and every time before build we need to install out certificate and after building our product we should authenticode our assemblies by that installed certificate.